# how filtering works on array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

My object array is as follows:

```
{
  user_id: '2',
  imagefilename: '/data/data',
  coordinates: [ { classes_id: 2, coordinate: [Array] } ]
}
```

array I want to create

```
  {
  user_id: '2',
  imagefilename: '/data/data'
  }
```

how can I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use destructuring:

```js
const A = { user_id: '2', imagefilename: '/data/data', coordinates: [ { classes_id: 2, coordinate: [Array] } ] }

const { coordinates, ...B } = A;

console.log(B);
```

this way, any A's properties that are specified will be omitted, and the rest of the properties will be added to B. For example if you want to exclude `imagefilename` field as well, you could use `const { coordinates, imagefilename, ...B } = A;`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [{ user_id: '2', imagefilename: '/data/data', coordinates: [ { classes_id: 2, coordinate: [Array] } ] }];

let output = arr.map(a => { return {user_id: a.user_id, imagefilename: a.imagefilename}})

console.log(output);
```

You could do this using the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to solve this.